# Не запускается python script из cron на ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

Не запускается python (3.6) script из cron на ubuntu 18.04 lts
Скрипт работает если запускать его из консоли
Как исправить ошибку?

Строка в /etc/crontab

```
*  *<-->* * *<->root<--> cd /home/yuriy_tigiev/solt/ && /usr/bin/python3 /home/yuriy_tigiev/solt/solt.py >> logs.txt  2>&1.
```

Ошибка в логе

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "/home/yuriy_tigiev/solt/solt.py", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                         
    import lib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/yuriy_tigiev/solt/lib.py", line 3, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                          
    import ccxt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ccxt'
```

Comment: посмотрите тут: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069494/python-module-not-found-when-launched-in-cron

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел в https://netassured.co.uk/executing-python-scripts-from-crontab/

Смысл - часть переменных из env скопировать в crontab

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/env
HOME=/home/nickm -- ваш домашний катало
```